# Handling custom file exception in Java

Tags: java, exception

I need help to throw my custom made exception.
I want to verify if the dummy file I created is invalid, throw my `BadFileException` and output the message, but it does not work.
Im not sure what's wrong as the exception is not thrown, i am not exactly sure what condition i can use to throw the exception based on the instructions in my *`TODO`*

```
   //TODO5: Add all the remaining code to open a file
   // and write the account details in a file
   // The format of the account to save should be a line like this:
   // FirstName,LastName,AccountNumber,StartDate
   // John,Winston,156-5555555,Wed Jan 23 00:00:00 EST 2019
   // You must catch the IOException and throw a 
   // BadFileException with message : Error Writing To File
   // The out must be caught by the calling method in
   // AccountLauncher class
```

```
public class b {
    static String fileName = "/myFolder/data.txt";

        static Account a = new Account();
        public static  boolean dff()   {

            //File f = new File("filename.txt");

             try {
                File f = new File("/myFolder/data.txt");

                FileWriter w = new FileWriter(fileName);
                w.write(a.toString());

                w.close();

                if(f.exists()==false) {          
                   throw new BadFileException("Error Writing To File");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

                return true;
        }
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Save the account details in a file
        b b1 = new b();
        try {
            if ( b1.dff() ) {
                System.out.println("Account Details Saved.");
            }
        } catch (BadFileException e) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly what "does not work?"  Also if you want to throw an exception for a test, just throw it.  You don't have to create a file first or anything.

Comment: From the TODO comment it looks like you want to catch the `IOException` then throw a `BadFileException` Something like this: `} catch(IOException e) { throw new BadFileException("Error Writing To File"); }`

Comment: @markspace well the the throw statement never executes .  Basically  i am not sure whether or not i need a condition before i throw my exeception . I am just following the TODO comment . i need the exeception to be thrown so it can be caught by the calling method in the main method

Comment: @Raghav Thank you very much i just tried your suggestion and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Raghav consider adding it as an answer

Comment: Great @Gabriel please consider marking my posted answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

From the TODO comment it looks like you want to catch the `IOException` then throw a `BadFileException`.

Something like this:

```
try {
    //...
} catch(IOException e) { 
    throw new BadFileException("Error Writing To File");
}
```